# ClickOnce : Deploy to linux server in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I'm using a linux&apache server as ClickOnce server.

I compress "Deploy" folder to `.tgz`, and send it to server by SFTP, and uncompress by ssh, then the deployment is finished.

By the way, I can use visual studio to deploy to IIS... Then, can I deploy ClickOnce to linux server in visual studio? If so, How can I do?